# Getting/Creating Java application Context on native side on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-context

I have native component, where no Activities are being created or ran. Since Android have most of the useful functionality in Java, I have no other idea to get ANDROID_ID than to use Java then. I have set up proof of concept code to do that in native and it works. But for that I have the instance jobject and of course JNIEnv. I want to somehow set it up so that I do not need to pass any java instance to my native code. That means that I somehow need to create/get the Context object. And after that I can get ContentResolver to get the ANDROID_ID. Since ANDROID_ID is constant and ContentResolver seems to be also same for all the activities I think there must be some way. I also think that Context is the same for all, but I do not have knowledge to be sure. Since I can do native code, but I do not know much Android App infrastructure, then can anyone suggest any solutions.

My thoughts:

1. Create some pseudoActivity in native code and kill it momentarily after getting the id.
2. Pass the Java jobject instance and get the context. (Works, but not wanted.)

Comment: Why do you have standalone native code? You should always be able to pass along some kind of Java reference.

Comment: Hey, misfit wording, fixed it. Yes you can, but I would not :) I am curious because the Application for example have 1 universally same Context... You can ask context.getApplicationContext(). So this hints that there should be some universal way to do it...

Comment: Why can't you just use the Application's context? Your code is tied to a process, which is (roughly) tied to Application lifecycle.

Comment: Can you show me how... When I have only JNIEnv in native available :)

Comment: Sorry, as far as I know, you'll need a java `Context` passed in. Try using an `Application` object instead of `Activity`